# How to shows nothing if a list of value is undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for this, maybe is an easy and basic question

I'm getting results from an endpoint but some of these values could be empty, then on my screen shows "undefined"

How can I check in a clean code if some of the value is undefined then show nothing?

```
myvalues() {
  if (!this.myendpointdata) {
    return '';
  }
  const { value1, value2, value3, value4 } =
    this.myendpoindata.master.values;
  return `${value1} ${value2} ${value3} ${value4}`;
}
```

This is my code. And, for example, value2 shows undefined

Comment: yes because you have made spelling mistakes in value2 :) which now Nick Vu has edited

Answer (score 2):

You can set empty strings if your values are `undefined`

```
myvalues() {
  if (!this.myendpointdata) {
    return '';
  }
  const { value1, value2, value3, value4 } =
    this.myendpoindata.master.values;
  return `${value1 || ""} ${value2 || ""} ${value2 || ""} ${value4 || ""}`;
}
```

You also can loop through values and filter not undefined values out for display

```
myvalues() {
  if (!this.myendpointdata) {
    return '';
  }
  const { value1, value2, value3, value4 } = this.myendpoindata.master.values;
  const values = Object.values({ value1, value2, value3, value4 });
  return values.filter(value => !value).join(" ");
}
```

Comment: that works!! Thanks.
On your first example how can I add an string after each value if the value is not empty? 

If I do something like return `${value1 || ""} - ${... will show the "-" even when the first value is empty

Comment: In that case, I'd prefer you use the 2nd way that will help you have cleaner and more readable code @Rola

Comment: @Rola I modified my 2nd approach to fit your case with 4 values instead of all values

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operations:

```
return `${value1 ? value1 : ''} ${value2 ? value2 : ''} ${value3 ? value3 : ''} ${value4 ? value4 : ''}`;
```